# How to avoid drag and drop traces in CN1

Tags: codenameone

As you can see in the animation below the dragging causes traces I don't want. Moreover the dragged component is drawn vertically shifted. I guess this has to do with the statusbar. But how can I avoid this as well?

[image]

this is my code:

```
class LockScreen: GenLockScreen() {

    var triggerOnUnlock: (() -> Unit)? = null

    override fun initComponent() {


        val draggable = StraightDraggableLabel(gui_Unlocker)
        replace(gui_Unlocker, draggable, null)

        gui_Unlocker = draggable
        gui_Unlocker.preferredSize = Dimension(gui_UnlockTarget.preferredW, gui_SlideArea.height)

        revalidate()

        // dragging

        draggable.apply {
            isVDragEnabled = false
            dragMinX = draggable.x
            dragMaxX = gui_SlideArea.x + gui_SlideArea.width
        }


        gui_UnlockTarget.isDropTarget = true
        gui_Unlocker.isDraggable = true
        gui_Unlocker.addDragOverListener {

            val overlap =  (gui_Unlocker.draggedx + gui_Unlocker.width) - gui_UnlockTarget.x
            val overlapRatio = overlap / gui_Unlocker.width.toDouble()

            if(overlapRatio >= 0.75) triggerOnUnlock?.invoke()
        }
    }
}


class StraightDraggableLabel(var isHDragEnabled: Boolean = true, var isVDragEnabled: Boolean = true): Label() {

    var dragMinX = Int.MIN_VALUE
    var dragMaxX = Int.MAX_VALUE
    var dragMinY = Int.MIN_VALUE
    var dragMaxY = Int.MAX_VALUE

    constructor(label: Label): this() {
        uiid = label.uiid
        text = label.text
        icon = label.icon
    }

    override fun getDragImage() = toImage()!!

    override fun drawDraggedImage(g: Graphics, img: Image, x: Int, y: Int) {
        //super.drawDraggedImage(g, img, x, y)
        val dX = if(isHDragEnabled) MathUtils.clamp(dragMinX, dragMaxX - img.width, x) else this.x
        val dY = if(isVDragEnabled) MathUtils.clamp(dragMinY, dragMaxY - img.height, y) else this.y

        g.drawImage(img, dX, dY)
    }
}
```

I omitted the designer specific files / classes.

The dragged green component is styled by css:

```
LockScreenUnlocker {
  background-color: #00a87f;
  border-radius: 2mm;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: large;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: This generally happens if a component is marked as opaque (bg transparency 255) but doesn't draw its entire content. Set the bgTransparency to 0.

Comment: but this makes the button transparent. And, in that case a trace of the arrow symbol gets caused. I actually need the green background color.

Comment: How do you draw the round rect is it with a border? Try setting transparency to 254 to see if this still happens.

Comment: I updated my main post concerning your question. Transparency with 254 doesn't help either.

Comment: Can you isolate a standalone test case in Java?

Comment: should I post it in github?

Comment: If you can isolate a standalone test case as this isn't something I can run/debug

Comment: I included the sample code here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2814